# How to define a map of sets in Go?

Tags: go, struct, set

I would like to know how to define a map of sets in Go. A set is a collection of unordered unique elements.

The sets are collections of a struct (Tile).
The key of the map is a string. The key is the combination of tile.X + "," + tile.Y.

What I have so far. It only works for one element, not a set.

```
type Tile struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func (t Tile) GetKey() {
    return strconv.Itoa(t.X) + "," + strconv.Itoa(t.Y)
}

// This only works for one element, not for a set.
type Cache map[string]Tile
```

Comment: you can define a map that has functionality of set like `map[Tile]bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to represent a set**

Sets in Go are [usually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34018908) represented with maps from the given type to a primitive value that defines its existence. The `map` type is how you can semantically represent an unordered collection of unique elements.

`var tileSet map[Tile]bool`

Note that you can use non-pointer `Tile` structs as map keys. because:

- map keys must be comparable ([Specs: Map Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types))
- `Tile`, based on how you defined it, is comparable ([Specs: Comparison Operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)), in particular:

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

...and clearly the two `int` fields `X` and `Y` are comparable.

This is how you use such a map:

```
tileSet = make(map[Tile]bool, 0)

tile := Tile{X:1,Y:2}
tileSet[tile] = true

// check existence
if exists := tileSet[tile]; exists {
   // ... 
}

// range over set elements
for tile, _ := range tileSet {
   // ...
}
```

**How to represent a map of set**

Trivially:

`var tileSetMap map[string]map[Tile]bool`

To simplify the code, you can also define your own set type:

`type TileSet map[Tile]bool`

and then

```
func main() {
    var tileSetMap map[string]TileSet

    // you initialize it normally with make
    tileSetMap = make(map[string]TileSet, 0)
    tileSetMap["foo"] = make(TileSet, 0)

    tile := Tile{10, 20}
    tileSetMap["foo"][tile] = true
    
    fmt.Println(tileSetMap) // map[foo:map[{10 20}:true]]
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ObUo62SI3ih

---

[1] Specs: [Map Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)

> The comparison operators == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type

Comment: Nice. I made some changes to the playground that you shared. https://play.golang.org/p/VBflnzqDRN4 Creating an Add function that creates the set when needed.